How to hide toctree navbar children with sphinx restructured text (rst)?
I have a 1-pager I'm linking to, but the h2 (---) is redundantly showing. Since it's only a single page, it looks funny and would really like to hide this.
Setup
conf.py

html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'

html_theme_options = { 'navigation_depth': 2 }



index.rst
=======
Welcome
=======

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :hidden:

   Foo Expecting 0 Children <foo>
   Bar Expecting Children In Same Toctree <bar>

foo.rst
===
Foo
===

Some H2
-------

The h2 above is showing as a left navbar toctree
child when it shouldn't since :maxdepth: is 1
(not 2).

bar.rst
It doesn't matter - just know it has children and I want them (all ok here).
Thought Process

I have navigation_depth of 2 for max depth (from what I understand)
I have :maxdepth: 1 to only show h1 children (h2 --- shouldn't be showing)
I have :hidden: so the toctree isn't redundantly thrown into the body (seems to be working)

Observations

Changing :maxdepth: doesn't seem to do anything, even if it's 0, -1 or !declared at all!
The only change that seems to make an impact is the navigation_depth theme opt, but this doesn't feel right: There's no way it's all-or-none.
I also tried removing navigation_depth completely, which still seemed to ignore :maxdepth: and gave some serious depth to the toctrees, so added it back to 2.

That said!

Let me know if this thought process matches what's expected
What can I do to fix my issue of Foo showing the h2 child in navbar when it's expected to only show h1 due to :maxdepth: 1 (if I'm understanding correctly)?

PS:

rubric is not the answer I seek; that's essentially an h5 that breaks consistency.
Css flags seems like a possible workaround, but not an answer.


Remove hidden and rebuild. Does the toctree appear correctly in the body of the page, not the navigation? If so, then make clean html should clean the cache and rebuild the docs. Also make sure your web browser does not cache a page, and that you are viewing the actual built files.
